# undefined is not an object while evaluating select options with mac OS X 10.9 with safari 7.0 in richfaces

Tags: jsf-2, safari, richfaces

Getting below error while selecting the values from the drop down. Application runs in mac OS X 10.9 and safari 7.0 combination with richfaces.

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating selectoptions[optindex].text)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: This is caused because of some unwanted script is called in my code. After removing it, it works fine. Thanks all for looking in to it.